# Should minification of css and js files be in a build step or done by hand?

Tags: javascript, css, minify

There is really two questions here.

1) should minification be done by hand or done as part of a build? 
2) should the minified files be version controlled?

I"m trying to define a go forward path for the current project that i'm working on. I've done some speed evaluations and I believe that my current site could have big performance improvements with just adding some compression / minification.

Here is the basic setup

IBM Commerce 6.0 
a ton of large js files (nothing has been minified or compressed)
a ton of large css files (nothing has been minified or compressed)

Comment: 1) In your deployment, because 2) You don't want to or need to version control your minified files, they're unreadable code made from readable code and are no use in dev.

Comment: If it can be done in build, why do it by hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> should minification be done by hand or done as part of a build?

As part of the build. That way you can't forget to do it. You don't usually need minified code in the development environment, you can build by hand if you find you need to debug problems that only reveal themselves in minified code.

You can test the minified code on your staging server.

> should the minified files be version controlled?

Not by your source control. If you have an archive of historic build artefacts then they should be part of that.

Comment: What if a problem only shows itself in a certain environment only? It's not uncommon.

Comment: Then "you can build by hand if you find you need to debug problems that only reveal themselves in minified code" (or you can manually deploy to staging and disable the minification step)

Comment: I guess you could but it adds more steps to the process. Suppose you fix the issue, re-deploy to the test environment and discover another bug a day later. Deploy by hand again?

Comment: Yes. Note that "Deploy by hand" does not mean "Manually copy all the files and manually set up all the configuration for the staging server". It means "Comment out the line in your build script that minifies the code, then run the build script with the staging server as the deploy target". (That said, if you get *that* many problems occurring on your staging server, then your development environment is insufficiently like your staging environment).

Answer (score 1):

That all depends.

Sometimes it's useful to have this done on the fly based on a configuration setting. For example, if you're deploying to a test environment and you have minified your JS and discover a bug that only occurs in that environment, it's often handy to flick a switch so your application starts serving un-minified source files for debugging.

Comment: that is actual the direction that I"m going. I have the following setup 1) Test Env (no compression / minification ) 2) certification (compression / minification option but not required) 3) production (compression / minification required)

Comment: I agree, it's something you should be able to toggle at will.

Answer (score -2):

you Can Use smartoptimizer That Can minify and compressed your JS and CSS

And Can cache This file Until No Change Happen In File.

[Download smartoptimizer](http://farhadi.ir/projects/smartoptimizer/)

one of the this website project  is about minify  and compressed js or CSS with php. the advantage of this program is detect js and css then minify  and compressed .if js or css  change   this program detect it and renew minify  and compressed file

Comment: How is that project related to the two specific questions?